# How can I block outlook 2016 from authenticating against our o365 exchange?

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

My org is looking to block the 2016 and earlier versions of outlook from being able to authenticate into the office 365 exchange.

We have disabled the ADFS endpoints for 2013 and earlier but it looks like for 206 I will have to create something like client rules,  REF:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/client-access-rules/procedures-for-client-access-rules

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/client-access-rules/client-access-rules

Only issue with this being that it looks like outlook 2016 and 2019 can share the same "client versions" so even with I use KQL to find what users are connecting to our tenant with, it seems to be impossible to identify the actual end users program.